# Elasticsearch group by with pagination

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a document which contains the following fields: Id, ProductCode, UserId, and DateTime.

Now I'd like to get all products purchased by some user.

I created the following query which returns what I want:

```
{
    "size" : 0,
    "query": {
        "term": { ... }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "group_by_productCode": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "productCode.keyword"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I have hundreds of products so I would like to pass in From and Size parameters.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can't you pass them as filters?

Comment: @ketanvijayvargiya Can you provide some code? I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Thanks!